# Keeping PowerShell Open after Running manage.py runserver

Tags: django, powershell

I am working with Python Django in Windows Vista Powershell. After I run python manage.py runserver , it asks me to CTRL-BREAK to stop the process. But after I typed that, Powershell stops the process and closes. Is there a way to stop the process and keep the Powershell open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try CTRL-C , in my powershell its working fine.